# Produce table with text and number with fprintf in Matlab

Tags: matlab, printf

I need to produce a table whose first 2 columns have text, and the remaining 2 have numbers. Something like this:

```
| Ford | Mustang | 1975 | 35 |
| Chev | Camaro  | 1976 | 38 |
```

I have the string in a cell, and the numeric variables in a matrix. I've tried with fprintf but can't make it work. I have no problems doing it in xlswrite, but I don't want to go that way. Any ideas please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `fprintf` in a loop like this:

```
fprintf(1, '| %8s | %8s | %4d | %2d |\n', ...
    company{i}, model{i}, year(i), otherNumber(i));
```

to write to stdout. You can also modify the `%#s` if you want different spacing in your table, or provide a different file descriptor to the first argument.